# Google Sheet Script - Function should return a JSON data but brings NULL

Tags: json, google-sheets, return-value

I'm trying to get a value from a JSON object from a URL for use in a Google Sheet.

This is the script:

```
        function getPricefromExchange() {
  
 
  var url = 'https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/tickers?exchange=binance&pair=DOT-USDT';
  var reponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = reponse.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  return data.tickers.price;
  
}
```

The JSON data is as follows:

```
{
"tickers":
[
{ "from":"DOT",
  "to":"USDT",
  "exchange":"Binance",
  "price":27.82}
]
}
```

The return of my function is NULL and however I change the return value (e.g.return data.price; or return data;) the return value stays at NULL.

What did I do wrong? I just want to have the price as return value.

Comment: This is really very difficult for someone else to diagnose. Have you tried using Postman or some other testable means of making the call? If not, I recommend you download Postman (it's free) and make the call through it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function test(){
  var url = 'https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/tickers?exchange=binance&pair=DOT-USDT';
  var reponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = reponse.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(data.tickers[0].price)
}
```

as you can see, tickers is not a parent, tickers is an array `[]` (with one element)